# Tailwind background image

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to add a background as an image using tailwind css, but nothing actually shows up.
the div i will provide below is inside a component which has 'use client'

```
<div className={`flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full bg-[${imageUrl}] before:content=[''] before:absolute before:w-full before:h-full  before:bg-[${hexColor}] clipped h-40 font-bold`}>
// code
// code
// code
</div>
```

this className above actually resolves into this:

`flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full bg-[https://--------------.com/website/5f43de9311725.jpg] before:content=[''] before:absolute before:w-full before:h-full  before:bg-[#1b1464] clipped h-40 font-bold`

the url is correct but i don't know whats wrong.

i need to achieve this [Image i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRvgK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string interpolation with Tailwind CSS className properties in React. See this section from Tailwind CSS documents about [dynamic class names](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names). In your case both `imageUrl` and `hexColor` variables are highly dynamic. Instead you should use inline styling or complete class names (e.g. `before:bg-red-500`).

For before pseudo element's background coloring, you can approach with a config based class names:

```js
const classNames = {
  'red': 'flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full before:content=[''] before:absolute before:w-full before:h-full before:bg-red-500 clipped h-40 font-bold',
  'blue': 'flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full before:content=[''] before:absolute before:w-full before:h-full before:bg-blue-500 clipped h-40 font-bold',

<div className={classNames[hexColor]} >
// code
// code
// code
</div>
};
```

But since you are expecting a hex color, it doesn't fit into categorizing as shown in the example. Then you should use inline styling. But then again, you can't use inline styling with pseudo elements, so instead of `::before` pseudo element you should create a child element inside your component and give it inline styling:

```js
<div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full clipped h-40 font-bold">
  // Use this child element as ::before pseudo element
  <div
    className="absolute w-full h-full"
    style={{ backgroundColor: hexColor }}
  ></div>
// code
// code
// code
</div>
```

For your component's background image use inline styling:

```js
<div
  className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full clipped h-40 font-bold"
  style={{ background-image: imageUrl }}
>
  <div
    className="absolute w-full h-full"
    style={{ backgroundColor: hexColor }}
  ></div>
// code
// code
// code
</div>
```

Comment: tried this, but still if i look over the css, there is no background-image there also for before bg is not working as well

Comment: @mikaelkhalil Sorry for confusion, my previous answer wasn't correct at all. See my edited answer. I hope it helps. By the way, you can use JIT (just-in-time) mode of Tailwind CSS but it's not recommended for several reasons.

Comment: still it doesn't work :(  ,if i add it in my globals.css , as background-image: url('-----') it does show up is there a way to create a variable for this url in global css and manipulate it from there?